# Non-primitive, unsupported type error in ADF when trying to read a Parquet file

Tags: pyspark, azure-data-factory, databricks, parquet

In Databricks, a df is generated and saved as a parquet file. Here is the schema:

```
root
 |-- dq_check_id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- data_attribute_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- dq_check_scope_number_of_records: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- dq_check_hit_number_of_records: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- snapshotdate: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- dq_execution_date: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- generated_by: string (nullable = false)
 |-- dq_check_outcomes: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- rule_output_cd: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- business_key: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- identifying_data_element_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- identifying_data_element_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- technical_key: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- pk_attr_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- pk_attr_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- dq_check_attributes: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dq_check_attr_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dq_check_attr_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dq_check_attr_seq: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- outcome_details: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- outcome_attr_id: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- outcome_attr_value: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- outcome_attr_seq: string (nullable = false)
 |-- generated_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Then, when trying to read this parquet file in ADF, this error arrives:

`Parquet file contained column 'dq_check_outcomes', which is of a non-primitive, unsupported type.`

[image]

Comment: You can read / write complex data types in ADF as a data flow, it is not supported in Copy Activity or datasets. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-parquet#data-type-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there is not a MAP or LIST in the parquet file.

https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ExternalTables/ComplexTypes.htm

Please look at the Microsoft documentation on supported options and data types.  At the top it states it does not support MAP/LIST.  My suggestion is to rebuild the parquet file, section by section until you fine the nested issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs-legacy#parquet-format

Here is an image to the table for reference.  It looks like all types are supported from your file.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I think arrays falls into a LIST